# Force IE9 to always start InPrivate browsing mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, regedit

I don't mean creating a shortcut that includes the -private option. I was wondering if there was a known reg edit that could be toggled to always have IE start in InPrivate mode no matter how a user starts it?

Comment: You could rename iexplore.exe iexplore2.exe, and create a .exe that just calls iexplore2.exe with the -private option. It might break things though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows7/RegistryTips/Miscellaneous/SetInPrivateFilteringforInternetExplorertoEnabledbyDefault.html

Hive: HKCU

Key: Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Safety\PrivacIE

DWORD Name: StartMode

DWORD Value: 1

Comment: Awesome, that's good to know. I'm wondering what your search term was and how many pages in it took to find that. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work for me for iE9. I had to create the 'Safety\PrivacIE' keys as they didn't already exist, but had no effect. I also tried the key 'FilteringMode' as [mentioned here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-inprivate-filtering-permanently-in-microsoft-internet-explorer-9-ie9-beta/).

Answer (score 2):

You can go to `Tools -> Internet Options`, and check the `Delete browsing history on exit` option. This is very nearly the same as having InPrivate turned on all the time. I believe the main difference is that toolbars and extensions aren't disabled, but if you don't want those, then just don't install them.

Comment: Ahh thank you, that makes sense I thought InPrivate did more then just that.

Comment: InPrivate also clears cookies while 'Delete browsing history' does not

Comment: It does if you uncheck `Preserve Favorite website data` in the `Delete Browsing History` dialog.